# Can you identify this resistor or resistance?

Tags: batteries, resistors, identification

I was just cheking my batteries and noticed that one doesn't charge. When I opened it, I found that this resistor is broken and is not allowing the charge to travel to the battery.

I would like to buy one but I don't know how to look for it.

[image]

The battery pack has four batteries, AA size, 1.2 V.

The radio is a Motorola Handie Pro Euro 446.

Comment: It looks like a diode to me.

Comment: hi, if it is a diode , how can i look for it?

Comment: It might have some faint writing around it, such as 1N400x.  It could have vastly different writing on it though, there are literally thousands of different diodes.  Regardless, they are used to either prevent the battery from being reversely connected to a charger, or sometimes as a temperature sensor but the pack will require three contacts.

Comment: For me, it is more probable this "device" is not a diode but an NTC Thermistor instead. I've seen a lot of NTC's in the "diode" packages (without black stripe).

Comment: A diode will have some type of non-symmetrical marking. Usually an ink band (ring) on one end. Use a magnifier to look for it.

Comment: the charger provides 5 volts for charge the battery,  there are 3 pins , a negative pole and 2 positives poles that are linked like in the picture

Comment: no marking at all

Comment: Try to search for 10k NTC in the DO-35 package.

Comment: thank very much to  you all , it seems that is a ntc thermistor after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is either a temperature sensor or a diode, or a diode used as a temperature sensor.

In either case it is unlikely to be broken.

The more likely cause for charging problems is that the battery cells have gone bad.

Most places advertising replacement batteries for the Motorola Handie Pro Euro 446 mention nickel cadmium cells.

NiCads often fail short circuit.  A bad cell "looks like" a short circuit to the charger.  The charger cannot charge a battery with dead cells.

Measure the voltage across each cell individually.  If the voltage is close to zero, then the cell is dead.

Your best bet is to order a complete replacement battery.  They are expensive, though.  The cells can be replaced, and are much cheaper than complete batteries - but you will need to have a spot welder to connect the cells.  A soldering iron won't do the job.